# Enzyme Internal Error: unknown node with tag 15 using React Boiler Plate

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-boilerplate, dandelion

Using Jest for my tests, I just downloaded and installed React Boilerplate with Dandelion Template and configured Jest, when running `npm test` this is what came up:

[image]

this is the test the error it pointing to:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { FormattedMessage, defineMessages } from 'react-intl';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import ConnectedLanguageProvider, { LanguageProvider } from '../index';
// import configureStore from '../../../configureStore';
import configureStore from '../../../redux/configureStore';

import { translationMessages } from '../../../i18n';

const messages = defineMessages({
  someMessage: {
    id: 'some.id',
    defaultMessage: 'This is some default message',
    en: 'This is some en message',
  },
});

describe('<LanguageProvider />', () => {
  it('should render its children', () => {
    const children = <h1>Test</h1>;
    const renderedComponent = shallow(
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages} locale="en">
        {children}
      </LanguageProvider>,
    );
    expect(renderedComponent.contains(children)).toBe(true);
  });
});

describe('<ConnectedLanguageProvider />', () => {
  let store;

  beforeAll(() => {
    store = configureStore({}, browserHistory);
  });

  it('should render the default language messages', () => {
    const renderedComponent = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedLanguageProvider messages={translationMessages}>
          <FormattedMessage {...messages.someMessage} />
        </ConnectedLanguageProvider>
      </Provider>,
    );
    expect(
      renderedComponent.contains(
        <FormattedMessage {...messages.someMessage} />,
      ),
    ).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

It is the default test that is included in. I went into the documentation and also I have been googleing for a solution, but I have been unable to find one. How can I solve this?